# Cast IQueryable<X> to IQueryable<Y> with better performance

Tags: c#, performance, casting, iqueryable

I have 2 different entities, `Entity1` and `Entity2`, with the very same properties. They are auto-generated from different views from DB and each view has its own Entity type.

I query these entities via :

```
protected generatedRepository<Entity1Type> _myRepository1;
_myRepository1.GetQueryable();

protected generatedRepository<Entity2Type> _myRepository2;
_myRepository2.GetQueryable();
```

I'm creating an API endpoint using OData, and I must return a `IQueryable<...>` to let the user apply OData filters to its request

When I want to return entities from `Entity1`, I just have to write :

```
public IQueryable<Entity1Type> Get()
{
    return _myRepository.GetQueryable();
}
```

and this new endpoint is accessible from /api/ControllerName?$ODataFilter=...

However, I'd like to return data conditionally from `_myRepository1` or `_myRepository2` **using the very same endpoint**

If I use the same signature, `Entity2Type` must be cast to `Entity1Type` to be returned

I tried

```
return _myRepository2.GetQueryable().Cast<Entity1Type>();
```

But it fails :

> Unable to cast the type 'MyEntities2' to type 'MyEntities1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I also tried :

```
return _myRepository2.GetQueryable().ToDTO<Entity2, Entity1>();
```

It works, but the views have more than 1M rows and it loads all rows, which is not acceptable

The `ToDto<>` method came from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819149

I also tried following @DavidG comment :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity2Type, Entity1Type>

return _myRepository2.GetQueryable().ProjectTo<Entity1>();
```

But it fails with this error :

> The entity or complex type 'Entity1Type' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

How can I create only one endpoint, returning queryable data from `_myRepository1` or `_myRepository2` with good performance ?

Comment: You can't cast but you should be able to select: `_myRepository2.GetQueryable().Select(c => new Entity1 { ... copy all properties here ... })`

Comment: It would probably work but as I have a lot of properties, is there any other way to do it automatically insead of select them one by one ?

Comment: If you don't want to write out all of the properties you could use Automapper and use the [`ProjectTo` feature](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).

Comment: @DavidG See my edit, I tried your solution but it keeps failing at execution-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution, but I'm not sure it's the most elegant :

I've changed my `Mapper.Map<>` like this :

```
public IQueryable<Entity2> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Entity2Type, Entity2Type>() //Yes, Entity2 to Entity2, no typo
        .ForMember(d => d.Prop1, option => option.MapFrom(src => someCondition ? src.Prop1 : src.Prop2))
        .ForMember(d => d.Prop3, option => option.MapFrom(src => someCondition ? src.Prop3 : src.Prop4))
        .IgnoreAllNonExisting();

    var query = opts.ApplyTo(_myRepository2.GetQueryable()) as IQueryable<Entity2>;
    var results = Mapper.Map<IList<Entity2>>(query.ToList());

    return results.AsQueryable();
}
```

It returns a `IQueryable<EntityB>`, so my user can use OData filters. They are applied thanks to `ApplyTo<>` (so before the request is executed), which avoids to load the entire table in memory but only returns the fetched results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a common DTO that match your 2 entities and write the proper projection.

```
return _myRepository2.GetQueryable().Select(e2 => 'write your projection from e2 to dto')
```

same for you entity1 :

```
return _myRepository1.GetQueryable().Select(e1 => 'write your projection from e1 to dto')
```

also about the ToDTO<T1, T2) exposed in the other post. There is a "ToList()" inside that execute the query.

Comment: As I have more than 50 properties and maybe more in the future, should I really project all properties one by one ? Is there any way to do it automatically (based on their name for example) ?

Comment: You can use the ToDto<> removing the ToList(). Or you can consider using a mapping tool like automapper to do the job

Comment: You can't use that ToDto here, because even without ToList it materializes the source collection (by doing foreach on it).